# How much space is available on the device containing a given file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount

In linux, given a path to a file, is there any way to tell which filesystem it is on?

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how much space is left on the drive that `/home/itsadok/bananas` is in. From `df` I can see how much space is left on the various mounted drives, but it's a hard to figure out which of them is relevant.

By the way, I want to do this from a script, so educated guesses are not allowed.

Comment: please change the question to reflect what you are really after ("How much space is available on the device containing a given file" or something like that).

Comment: You're right. Although I would be interested in an answer to the original question.

Comment: Heh. Just realized this *is* an answer to the original question, since df tells you which filesystem it is.

Comment: My vote goes to the original title (if only to find it at some later time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run

```
df -k /home/itsadok/bananas
```

*(-k for size in kilobytes, you can ignore it if you don't want it)*

This will give you the size left for only the filesystem containing the file, at least on AIX.

Comment: works properly on RHEL as well

Comment: also, fwiw, I personally prefer the `-h` option for human-readable sizes

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu and Solaris.

Comment: if you run across installations where df doesn't like a file argument, give it a directory argument instead: `df -k $(dirname /home/itsadok/bananas)` (or use backticks instead of `$( )`)

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with **df** after reading this question and I think this might be of help to someone:
To get it in a script, you have to remove the title line, that is, just keep the output line which has the text **/dev/sda1**. So I did this:

```
$ df -h . | grep dev
```

which gave me this:

```
/dev/sda1              41G  3.6G   36G  10% /
```

And to get the **36G** part, i did this:

```
$ df -h . | grep dev | cut -d' ' -f20
```

Playing around with **cut** gives the other parts also:

```
$ df -h . | grep dev | cut -d' ' -f1
/dev/sda1
```

As **itsadok** points out below, **awk** is better for this purpose since a change in number of spaces and/or field widths will break a **cut** based solution.
So this is better:

```
$ df -h . | grep dev | awk '{print $4}' 
36G
```

Comment: `cut` seems a little fragile for this purpose, I think the numbers won't with different drive sizes. I would use `awk '{print $3}'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is in a script:

```
stat -fc '%a * %S' -- "$fname" |bc
```